# Условный оператор

Tags: javascript, if, условия

Привет, не пойму, где прописать оператор присвоения, в условии.
Получается у меня такое условие, но если переменная больше нуля надо при помощи этого оператора умножить переменную на 5. Я предполагаю, что должно выглядеть как-то так, но у меня пишет ошибку. Что не так?

```js
let b = 10;
if(b == 0){
console.log(1);
} else if(b < 0) {
console.log('less then zero');
} else(b > 0){
b *= 5;
} console.log();
```

Comment: После `else` не может быть условия

Comment: Ааа, а можно прописать тогда это условие в консоли вывода?

Comment: Зачем вам это условие? И вообще опишите нормально задачу

Comment: Условие задачи: дана переменная, если она равна 0 выводится 1, если меньше 0 выводится строка 'less then zero', а если больше, то использовать оператор присвоение и умножить переменную на 5.

Comment: BTW, грамотно будет «less thAn zero»

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> } else(b > 0){
> ```

```
} else if (b > 0) {
```

Но вообще, лучше делать по-нормальному и последнее условие вообще не писать.

> Оно выводит undefined

Потому что

> ```
> console.log();
> ```

```
console.log(b);
```

Comment: Cпасибо большое, теперь всё понятно.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (b<0) {
   console.log('less then zero');
} else if (b==0) {
   console.log(1);
} else {
   b *= 5;
};

console.log('Задача выполнена');
```

Comment: `else if` - это устоявшаяся идиома. Нет никакого смысла разбивать ее на три разные строчки.

Comment: Почему так сложно отформатировать 10 строк в читабельный вид?

Comment: @PavelMayorov Читайте маны: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/816-6408-10/stmt.htm#1004833 `else if` в JavaScript - не существует!

Comment: Оно выводит undefined

Comment: "if (b=0)" будет всегда истина, тк это оператор присвоения

Comment: @DiDex Да, спасибо. Поправил.

Comment: ааа, в таком случае надо ставить ещё 1 равно?

Comment: уже поняла, спасибо

Comment: @DiDex, с каких пор 0 - истина? о_О

Comment: @Akina как составная конструкция - еще как существует. Заметьте, я написал "идиома", а не "ключевое слово".

Comment: @PavelMayorov Я вроде дал ссылку. Где совершенно чётко написано, что при наличии `else` после этого слова (без учёта пробельных символов) обязательно идёт открывающая блок фигурная скобка, безальтернативно. Это в JScript есть `else if` - но автор указал тегом именно JavaScript.

Comment: @Akina по вашей ссылке информация противоречива. Сразу после этого требования идет пример где никакой фигурной скобки нету.

Comment: @Akina вот правильная ссылка: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-if-statement

Comment: @PavelMayorov Ну это уже к Ораклу претензии...

Comment: @Akina Оракл не является организацией которая утверждает стандарт Javascript и никогда не являлся ей

Comment: @Akina источник стандарта языка - Ecma International, Technical Committee 39

Comment: @PavelMayorov Это стандарт ECMAScript. А JavaScipt и JScript - это реализации ("сочинения на тему") этого стандарта, каждая со своими расширениями, дополнениями, интертрепациями и прочими закидонами.

Comment: @Akina когда вопрос касается Javascript в общем, а не реализации в конкретном браузере - надо смотреть стандарт Ecmascript, в таком контексте это синонимы.

Comment: @Akina и да, мне не знакома ни одна реализация Javascript которая бы требовала обязательной фигурной скобки.